# IIS Web config authentication section

Tags: iis, authentication

Despite this being a question related to programming, it's really more about understanding the functionality of IIS 8.

In my web application, I'm trying to get the authentication section of my web.config. As far as I understand, the settings in IIS 8 affect the web.config. But no change seem to affect the authentication section. It always shows `Windows`.

How could this work? Neither the web.config in my root directory (%windir%\Microsoft.NET\Framework\framework_version\CONFIG) nor the config file in my application directory have an authentication section defined.

Where does this come from? What does IIS actually do, when I set authentication to anonymous?

Comment: authentication to anonymous simply means that anyone can vie the site. The security I think you are talking about, at least in regard to .Net and ASP or web API, MVC, etc, is set up through the web app, not to be confused with desktop app. this link covers those 3 https://www.google.com/#q=tutorial+web+security+Identity+.net&spf=1499438845348 in the search results as the top three results. And this link discusses IIS security a bit more https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj635855(v=ws.11).aspx Suffice it to say there is a bit to learn here. The ApplicationPool plays a key role in IIS8

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Authentication is a setting-group of IIS and has nothing to do with `.NET` so that is why it is not in the global web.config file.

There are two files which determine IIS's global behavior:

`%systemroot%\System32\inetsrv\config\applicationHost.config`

which has server-wide settings and settings for any web-sites, virtual directories and applications if delegation as not been enabled for a feature.

`%systemroot%\System32\inetsrv\config\schema\IIS_schema.xml`

which defines the XML schema that IIS uses and has default values defined for certain settings. (this is read-only)

If you are changing settings in the GUI and can not find them in your web.config file, they are most likely in `applicationHost.config`